Extract gps location data from mp4 video with help of ffmpeg c++ library
Are there some way to extract gps data location from mp4 video file in ffmpeg c++ library like exiftool:
exiftool -ee -n -p "$gpslatitude,$gpslongitude,$gpsspeed,$gpsdatetime" test.mp4 > gps.csv
I try to use av_dict_get() and av_dict_iterate() functions but without any positive result :-(

You're unlikely to find anything because it's such a monumental task. There isn't a standard for including GPS data in a video, except for one by Google that is used by only a few drones. Exiftool currently reads 77 different formats of timed GPS metadata from video files with about a half dozen more that haven't been deciphered, as the companies that add the data often obfuscate the data. The exiftool author has been working on this since Jan. 4, 2018.

I thought you were asking about time GPS, such as a GPS track. If you were looking for a single location in the file, then my apologies.

Try with ffprobe:
ffprobe -i file.mp4 -print_format json -show_format

It will output json. In my tests there is a object format.tags.location which contains a string like "+34.5570+30.4124"
If you add -show_streams, you will get streams description. In some cases (drone footages) there is a mov_text stream which contains data about gps position and speed in form of subtitles. To extract subtitles use following command:
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 subs.srt

